# NCalc specify type

Tags: c#, ncalc

We have a generic calculation routine using Ncalc to evaluate a string. However we are running across a problem when the values in a multiplication are small enough that Ncalc sees them as int however the result is too big for an int.

Example:

```
        var expr = new NCalc.Expression("1740263 * 1234");
        object result = expr.Evaluate();
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

This results in a negative int value.

Is there any way to force Ncalc to use long for the calculation?

I have tried using parameters and this works but it would mean a major rewrite of our code to implement and I would like to avoid it if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NCalc uses `Int32` as integer data type then you can't force a number to be calculated as `Int64`. However if you don't use built-in math functions and you rely on *plain* mathematical operators you may convert a number to `long` and it will invoke correct operators. Let's see it:

```
var expr = new NCalc.Expression("CLng(1740263) * 1234");
expr.EvaluateFunction += delegate(string name, NCalc.FunctionArgs args)
{
    // Nostalgic CLng function...
    if (String.Equals(name, "CLng", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        args.HasResult = true;
        args.Result = Convert.ToInt64(args.EvaluateParameters()[0]);
    }
};
```

Please note that you can't directly cast boxed `Int32` parameter to `Int64` then you have to use `Convert.ToInt64()` or double cast: `(long)(int)args.EvaluateParameters()[0]`. Now you can check result is correct:

```
var result = expr.Evaluate();
Console.WriteLine("Result is: {0} (type {1})",
    result, result.GetType());
```

Proper type conversion is performed then you don't need to *cast* both values to `long`.

Note that you may also directly use floating point numbers (`decimal` in NCalc) and you won't have such problems:

```
var expr = new NCalc.Expression("1740263.0 * 1234.0");
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. It has helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract all the number from the string, replace them with parameters and then set the parameters to the converted numbers. In this example I am replacing what would of been int numbers to decimal.

```
string myCalculationString = "1000000 * 10000000";
striny myPattern = @"-?\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+(e\d+)?)?";

MatchCollection matches =
Regex.Matches(convertedCalculation, myPattern );

int matchCount = 0;
convertedCalculation = Regex.Replace(convertedCalculation,
myPattern , m => "[p" + matchCount++ + "]");

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    {
       Match match = matches[i];
       decimal number = Convert.ToDecimal(match.Value);
       expression.Parameters.Add($"p{i}", number);
    }

 decimal result = (decimal)expression.Evaluate();
```

Note I have not tested the regular expression well but it seems to work for positive/negative numbers and allows optional decimal point. This will also throw an error if any of the numbers or the result is out of bounds for a decimal